# Crontab every monday syntax

Tags: cron

I created a cron date but couldn't be sure. I want to run every monday at 16:25. I got help from https://crontab.guru. According to crontab.guru every monday at 16:25 is

```
25 16 * * MON
```

Yo can check here https://crontab.guru/#25_16_*_*_MON . I checked the this time on https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html but not working. According to freeformatter must be 0 25 16 ? * MON * and next execution dates is correct. Which one is correct. Which one should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe different cron implementations have different syntax.

For example, crontab.guru refers to [cronitor](https://cronitor.io/cron-job-monitoring?utm_source=crontabguru&utm_campaign=cronitor_top) as mentioned on the website:

> crontab guru: The quick and simple editor for cron schedule expressions by **Cronitor**

Similarly, freeformatter refers to [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) as mentioned on their website:

> Generate a **quartz** cron expression with an easy to use online interface.

> Which one should I use?

So I believe that depends on what cron you're using. For me, using crontab.guru worked fine for scheduling jobs on MacOS.

Comment: Then both will work right? I will use on centos server. I need to check somethings on server?

Comment: I would just try doing simple stuff, for example, creating a file every minute or so and see if it works. [According to this article](https://linuxhint.com/a-beginners-guide-to-crontab-on-centos/), the crontab.guru syntax seems to be working for CentOS.